# Issues with game over screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an issue with my "game over" screen. I'm using classes and fairly new to them.
Here is the error I get:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at DocumentClass/onAvatarDeath()    at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/flash.events:EventDispatcher::dispatchEventFunction()
>     at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()    at MethodInfo-31()

and this is the `onAvatarDeath()` method within the `DocumentClass`:

```
public function onAvatarDeath( avatarEvent:AvatarEvent ):void
{
    var travelScore:Number = playScreen.getTravelScore();
    var coinScore:Number = playScreen.getCoinScore();
    gameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen();
    gameOverScreen.addEventListener( NavigationEvent.RESTART, onRequestRestart );
    gameOverScreen.x = 275;
    gameOverScreen.y = 125;
    gameOverScreen.setTravelScore( travelScore );
    gameOverScreen.setCoinScore( coinScore );
    addChild( gameOverScreen );

    playScreen = null;
}
```

My menu screen works pretty much the same, and it works fine. When I trace the `playScreen` it is `null`, which is fine. But when I trace the ~game over~ screen it doesn't trace... Any help? I'm lost.

Comment: If `playScreen` is `null` it is NOT fine, because you are trying to call two methods on it: `getTravelScore()` and `getCoinScore()`. Therefore this produces the error you have encountered.

Comment: You cant call function on null object, of course! Add check like: if (!playScreen) return;

Comment: im still unclear what to do, could you give me an example?

Comment: If `playScreen` is null, then that's why Flash is complaining about a "null object reference", because `playScreen.getTravelScore()` is trying to work with something that doesn't exist. You'll need to check where playScreen is set, and where it's set to null, and make sure it's still available when `onAvatarDeath()` runs. (Maybe `onAvatarDeath()` is running more than once, and the last line is causing it?)

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at your files, your game keeps running even after the player dies (specifically, `avatarEnterFrame` keeps being called). This means that `onAvatarDeath` gets run over and over, but because you set `playScreen` to null the first time, Flash can't find it when it tries to do `getTravelScore` or `getCoinScore`.

I normally have a variable like `var isGameRunning:Boolean = false;` that I keep updated when the game starts or the player dies (or wins), then put `if (gameRunning)` around the whole of any functions like `avatarEnterFrame`.

Alternatively, you could remove the `ENTER_FRAME` listener on `avatar` when the player dies, (but obviously remember to add it again when the player restarts the game).